# Boost MPL at template overload missing?

Tags: boost-mpl

I'm trying to do a POC of policy based design using the boost-mpl's map container. [(code here)](http://pastebin.com/rL9PaUwg)

I pass my policies around using an mpl::map, which is empty by default :

```
typedef boost::mpl::map<> DefaultPolicy;
```

To get the policy I tried the following:

```
typedef typename boost::mpl::at<TPolicy, LogPK, DefaultLogP>::type LoggingPolicy;
```

Instead, I'm getting the following error with g++ 4.81 (and an equivalent one with clang++ 3.3):

> ```
> main.cpp:49:61: error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be 2)
>     typedef typename boost::mpl::at<TPolicy, LogPK, DefaultLogP>::type LoggingPolicy;
>                                                                ^
> ```

The boost documentation [mentions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/at.html) a three-arguments overload for the at template. It looks like it's not located in `#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>`. I even searched this overload throught the boost code, without success. The only template I found is the one with two arguments. I failed at googling this issue ("at" is too common).

Is it a boost documentation bug, or has anyone found out how to use this mpl::at overload ?

Comment: *facepalm*. I've finally found the [trac issue](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3982) of this (at least) three years old documentation bug.

Answer (score 2):

There's only the 2-type version. The documentation is unfortunately wrong and has been forever. But you can always roll your own

```
template <typename Seq, typename Key, typename Def>
struct at_def
: mpl::eval_if<
    typename mpl::has_key<Seq, Key>::type,
    mpl::at<Seq, Key>,
    mpl::identity<Def>
    >
{ }
```